# Can I use symbol links in Android to move programs onto the SD card when they insist on being on harddrive?

Tags: linux, sd-card

I have a Sony Ericsson Xperia Pro Mini with Cyanogenmod OS.

One of the most frustrating things about it is that many applications want to be on the phone instead of the SD card, but the phone has very limited memory which is always running out, causing my phone to become slow and unstable.

Meanwhile my SD card is mostly empty.

I realize that under the hood, Cyanogenmod is Android, which in turn in Linux, so I expect (in theory) I should be able to create symbolic links (though I'm hardly a Linux guru).

- Is it possible to create symbolic links and move applications and/or their data from the phone to the SD?
- What can/should I move?
- What would be the risks of moving these?
- What should I absolute never move?
- What would be the safest method way (either using software or the command line) to move that which can/should be moved?

Answer (score 1):

Afaik [Link2SD](http://www.link2sd.info/) does precisely this - it moves apps to sd leaving properly designed symlinks only at where they were before.

Comment: Cheers for the response.  Unfortunately, I've read the reviews and it seems that users are generally unhappy and not getting adequate support.  Perhaps a different application or a manual solution would be better.

Comment: @BrianKessler Well it certainly requires some technical work (like creating and formatting a partition, etc.), maybe app2sd or some other app is easier. But in any case doing it manually requires more work without any support :D

Comment: I don't mind doing manual work, as long as I have some idea what is happening (or supposed to be).  And if I need support, google and stackexchange are my friends.  :-)

Comment: @BrianKessler OK then maybe some info on the Link2SD home page can help you

Comment: Will be sure to check out.  Thanks again.  :-)

Comment: You may find Apps2SD (literally, there are several entirely different apps called similarly) based on Link2SD more convenient, it is more automated